# How to merge different trees by filename

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn

Lets say I've the scenario bellow in SVN:

```
/projectOne/subprojectOne/**foldername1.one/file1.cs**
/projectOne/subprojectOne/**foldername2.one/file2.cs**
/projectOne/subprojectOne/**foldername3.one/file3.cs**

/projectOne/subprojectTwo/**foldername1.two/file1.cs**
/projectOne/subprojectTwo/**foldername2.two/file2.cs**
/projectOne/subprojectTwo/**foldername3.two/file3.cs**
```

My project "projectOne" has two mini-projects inside, with the same structure ("foldername1...", "foldername2...", "foldername3...") but with some differences withing the files ("file1.cs", "file2.cs", "file3.cs").

I've worked in **subprojectOne** and now I want to (merge) apply all modifications made to the **subprojectTwo**, assuming they have the same folder structure.

Already tried to merge using "merge differente trees" but didn't end well.

How can I do it using tortoiseSVN or SVN command line itself?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we're talking about a single repository, you can do as follow:

1. Head to a preferably clean (with no local changes) working copy that points to target branch `/projectOne/subprojectTwo`.
2. Right click on folder `projectOne` and choose "TortoiseSVN/ Merge".
3. Pick "Merge a range of revisions".
4. At "URL to merge from" set the full URL to source branch, e.g. `https://example.com/svn/projectOne/subprojectOne/`.
5. At "Revision range to merge" you can either merge all revisions at one or select a range. In either case, it doesn't hurt to click on "Select log" and review what's left to merge.
6. Click "Next" and review merge options. Default ones should be fine.
7. Optionally, click "Test merge" to figure out if you'll be getting conflicts.
8. Click "Merge" and cross your fingers.

   If you get merge conflicts TortoiseSVN will collect information and propose actions for each individual case. This can be hard part.
9. Review local changes, make additional tweaks if needed and commit.

If something goes wrong or you're unsure of what your're doing, you can just revert your working copy changes.